# How to automatically select the first option in a dropdown menu in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drop-down-menu, vuejs3, inertiajs

I have 2 dropdown menus, the second one changes values depending on the selection of the first dropdown.

All I want to do is set the first value of the second dropdown to be selected by default no matter what the option in the first dropdown is.

At the moment, the default selection of the second dropdown is always empty.

I tried fetching the values from `types` and loading them via `v-for` on the `option` tag and setting `:selected="index===0"` but it didn't work either.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-flower-2hjox1?file=/src/App.vue

The Template

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label for="type" class="form-label">Type</label>
  <select id="type" class="form-select" v-model="form.type">
      <option value="en-US" selected>English (US)</option>
      <option value="en-GB">English (British)</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label for="selected" class="form-label">Option 2</label>
  <div v-if="form.type === 'en-GB'">
      <select id="selected" name="selected" class="form-select" v-model="form.selected">
          <option value="Arsenal">Arsenal</option>
          <option value="Chelsea">Chelsea</option>
          <option value="Liverpool">Liverpool</option>
      </select>
  </div>
  <div v-else-if="form.type === 'en-US'">
      <select id="selected" name="selected" class="form-select" v-model="form.selected">
          <option value="Lakers">Lakers</option>
          <option value="Bulls">Bulls</option>
          <option value="Mavericks">Mavericks</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        type: 'en-GB',
        selected: ''
      },
      types: {
        american: ['Lakers', 'Bulls', 'Mavericks'],
        british: ['Arsenal', 'Liverpool', 'Chelsea']
      }
    }
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        type: "en-GB",
        selected: "",
      },
      types: {
        american: ["Lakers", "Bulls", "Mavericks"],
        british: ["Arsenal", "Liverpool", "Chelsea"],
      },
    };
  },
  watch: {
    'form.type': {
      handler() {
        this.form.selected = this.form.type === "en-GB" ? this.types.british[0] : this.types.american[0]
      },
      immediate: true
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="type" class="form-label">Type</label>
    <select id="type" class="form-select" v-model="form.type">
      <option value="en-US" selected>English (US)</option>
      <option value="en-GB">English (British)</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="selected" class="form-label">Option 2</label>
    <div v-if="form.type === 'en-GB'">
      <select
        id="selected"
        name="selected"
        class="form-select"
        v-model="form.selected"
      >
        <option value="Arsenal">Arsenal</option>
        <option value="Chelsea">Chelsea</option>
        <option value="Liverpool">Liverpool</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="form.type === 'en-US'">
      <select
        id="selected"
        name="selected"
        class="form-select"
        v-model="form.selected"
      >
        <option value="Lakers">Lakers</option>
        <option value="Bulls">Bulls</option>
        <option value="Mavericks">Mavericks</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can create watcher and set default values for second select:

```
watch: {
  'form.type': {
    handler() {
      this.form.selected = this.form.type === "en-GB" ? this.types.british[0] : this.types.american[0]
    },
    immediate: true
  }
}
```

Comment: This is setting the value of the `en-GB` option but when I switch to `en-US` the first option is empty.

Comment: @Halnex hey mate, check the snippet pls

Comment: Thanks man! I replaced the ternary operator with a switch case since I have more than 2 dropdowns and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

> All I want to do is set the first value of the second dropdown to be
> selected by default no matter what the option in the first dropdown
> is.

Add a watcher, which watches `form.type`, then pick the first item from `types`

Note, I've changed `american` key to the key your using for `type`, then you can loop over the options, if you don't have that in place you'll need mapping object anyway `typeMap: {'en-US': 'american', 'en-GB': 'british' }`  ... `types[typeMap[form.type]]`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        type: 'en-GB',
        selected: ''
      },
      types: {
        'en-US': ['Lakers', 'Bulls', 'Mavericks'],
        'en-GB': ['Arsenal', 'Liverpool', 'Chelsea']
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    'form.type' () {
      this.form.selected = this.types[this.form.type][0]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.15/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="type" class="form-label">Type</label>
    <select id="type" class="form-select" v-model="form.type">
      <option value="en-US" selected>English (US)</option>
      <option value="en-GB">English (British)</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="selected" class="form-label">Option 2</label>
    <select id="selected" name="selected" class="form-select" v-model="form.selected">
      <option v-for="name in types[form.type]">{{ name }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```